# Need to Close Page from Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a Page(Homepage.xaml), when I click a button on this page it opens a prompt(Prompt.xaml).

[image: Prompt]

This prompt is just a Window that I've made and executed using a `window.ShowDialog();` method in the Homepage.cs. I've been able to add a little code and when the NO button is clicked the prompt window is closed, now where I'm finding trouble is the YES button.

What I want is for the YES button to take me back to `MainWindow`, which I've been able to achieve so far, but when it opens the previous Homepage.xaml
is still there and I don't know how to close the Page from the prompt window, if that's even possible?

Another thing is, when the `MainWindow` opens it kinda pops up, can I make it so that it just lands on the page instead of opening/popping up like a new program?
Heres the Code.

**Homepage.cs**

```
public partial class User_Homepage : Page
{
    public static Page pager { get; set; } 

    public User_Homepage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void UserLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lovmsgb = new Custom_MessageBoxes.LogoutVerification();
        lovmsgb.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Prompt.cs**

```
public partial class LogoutVerification : Window
{
    public LogoutVerification()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void YesLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

        MainWindow window = new MainWindow() { WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen};
        window.Show();
    }
    private void NoLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And **MainWindow.cs** just in case

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void BtnClickP1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainFrame.Content = new Page1();
    }
    private void AdminBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainFrame.Content = new Page3();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check what button was clicked you should assign `DialogResult` in your DialogWindow:

```
    private void YesLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }
    private void NoLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = false;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Now make method to call dialog in your MainWindow and pass it as argument to Page1:

```
    private void AskDialog()
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            mainFrame.Content = null;
        }
        else
        {
            // False action
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        frame.Content = new Page1(AskDialog);
    }
```

In Page1 just call this action after button is pressed:

```
    public User_Homepage(Action askDialog)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AskDialog = askDialog;
    }
    private readonly Action AskDialog;
    private void UserLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AskDialog();
    }
```

Comment: OK, now how do I close the Page1 when the Window opens?

Comment: Did you check my example? mainFrame.Content = null; - this should clear yours control, so no page will be present.

Comment: Oh, this is kinda late but the page that logs out isn't Page1, page1 is the 2nd page i.e mainwindow - > page1 - > logout window, so how do I go from log out window straight to mainwindow?

Comment: Maybe you should provide more code? By calling action AskDialog you can call dialog from mainwindow, no mather what page call it.

Comment: What using directive does the "Dialog" type use?